# Can you have more than one companion?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

In Betrayal at the house on the hill, can you have more than one companion with you such as dog, girl, madman. Or do you have to discard one of the companions once you draw a second one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have more than one companion.

Nothing in the rules says you can't, also the Dog, Girl and Madman cards say on them that they cannot be dropped, traded or stolen.